# Sharepoint 2010 Development Environment Set-up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need advise on what can be best way to setup/configure SHAREPOINT 2010 Environment for 6-members teams (with 3-working at onsite and 2-working at offshore)

Currently I only had two team members but team is nowincreasing. What we have is DEVELOPMENT SERVER - with Visual Studio and Sharepoint Server installed. Developers remote VNC to the box and do their development.

But with number of developers are increasing what should be ideal, so that team can communicate from offshore/onshore

Is this Ideal (installed on each developer laptop) Visual Studio 2010 and Sharepoint Server (Installed on Windows Server 2008) and developers will use this rather than installing sharepoint locally (enterprise edition is very expensive)

Appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 1):

For a development environment with multiple users, definitely use a separate SharePoint server (single server farm) for each developer. Running multiple developers on one is a nightmare. Whether you're using laptops or virtuals, rdp, vnc, etc. would be up to you and your team. I have SharePoint on my laptop in a virtual instance, and for one customer I remote desktop to a provided virtual dev environment. It all depends on your preference.

Comment: Thanks. But Sharepoint Server Enterprise Edition is quite expensive, installing on six developer laptop will be too expensive.

Comment: You can get away with the trial version

Comment: Thanks for advise. Company is not allowing to install trial version. Production used sharepoint enterprise, but if i install foundation edition which is free then can't do testing of enterprise features locally on laptop.

Comment: SharePoint on development machines is licensed either through an MSDN license or part of your VL agreement. You certainly do not need to buy the full enterprise license if the farm is not for production use.