# What is the Best Way to Set Up a Development Server for Sharepoint?

Tags: 2010, development, windows-server, licensing

Let me qualify my question with these points:

- There is only one developer.
- The developer is the server administrator.
- The production server is Windows 2008, iis7.5, Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise, and we have a copy of VS 2010 Enterprise, and Active Directory.
- We are too poor to buy another server, but we can purchase a workstation
- I prefer to work from my workstation with a RDP connection to the server.

Some questions I thought of:

- Is there a way to do the development from my workstation?
- Will installing Sharepoint and Windows Server on my dev machine require a second set of licenses, or are the ones I have for production sufficient (and M$ understands)?
- Do I need to *purchase* another license for VS and SP2010?
- Is it preferable use a virtual machine or a real machine?

I found this post, which is related:
[Sharepoint 2010 Development Environment Set-up](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30266/sharepoint-2010-development-environment-set-up)

What I am leaning toward is to purchase a 64-bit system with Windows 7 and lots of RAM and using that for development (right now I am still using XP).

**[edit]**
The idea of using a virtual drive is quite appealing, and it appears that extra licenses must be purchased for that too - but aren't licenses for VS and Sharepoint (and Server) only good for a few installations?  With that in mind, it seems a regular hard drive (SSD, as is pointed out below) would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep with the minimal HW & SW prerequisites (i'm using for many months on my DELL Latitude D6510 - 8GB RAM, 320 HDD, Windows 7 X64 as a development environment.

If its a development you could even consider VHD boot to build your BASE Windows 7 X64 VHD Expandable (choose MAX 100 GB - VS2010, etc. takes a lot of space and EXPANDABLE) and create differential disks for your SharePoint 2010 specific environments - this should gain a lot of time.

In these conditions you can even consider using the Trial Versions (unless you have already licenses).

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do you mean by HW and SW?  Also, please describe for me what you mean by "BASE" and "EXPANDABLE".  Methinks you are talking over my (hard) head!

Comment: 1. HW & SW= Hardware & Software
2. When working with VHD boot you can create a Base disk on which you install Windows+ drivers+ sql+..etc. and use it as the basis for anything later. Use CREATE VDISK FILE="D:\W7_base.vhd" MAXIMUM=102400 TYPE=Expandable" - 100GB Max. (parent disk will never take all space, but child disks will). Once you install all base SW you can create multiple differential disks with stuff already installed, using (in CMD > DISKPART) CREATE VDISK FILE=D:\VHD\W7_SP2010.vhd" PARENT="D:\VHD\W7_Base.VHD"  - this will get you the CHILD disk to install ONLY SharePoint.

Comment: (Sorry I didn't get the SW and HW...) Thanks for the clarifications.  How does developing on the VHD differ from using a regular installation?

Comment: Is absolutely the same, but with VHD you basically have the OS running in a single file. Performance penalty around 3% apparently, but instead re-installing the whole OS you start from a base previously prepared! Besides, you don't have the penalty of running 2 host OS as in the case of using virtualization.

Comment: This is interesting (I gave you my +1), but where do I look for a good guide for this?  It sounds to me like you are describing a sort of Virtual "template" for an operating system, and then applying replaceable "children".

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx to get you started.

Comment: Oh that does look scary.

Comment: So am I thinking correctly when I say your methodology is like using a template for the OS and then using child pages for the additions, such as sharepoint?  That would mean that I could use the same VHD to test with Sharepoint ON and Sharepoint OFF, right?

Comment: Basically you would: create a new VHD (remember params), boot via your USB bootable with W7, launch Diskpart, attach the VHD and simply run Windows install. Once you're done you now have a BASE VHD (don't change it anymore - ReadOnly). Simply reboot in USB again, run DISKPART, create a NEW VHD using as PARENT the previous disk, use BCDEDIT to update boot settings (clone entry and re-target the NEW VHD -no longer the BASE) and from now on you only use this one for your work. If you need another configuration, make again new VHD with BASE as PARENT. It sounds scary, now i do it in 20'

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3374/discussion-between-bgm-and-c-marius)

Comment: There are many good answers here.  However, I marked this one because it is very detailed, and gave me the most inspiration to actually _want_ to try a virtual machine for sharepoint developement.  Thanks, Mr. Marius!

Comment: @c-marius Would you be willing to talk with me some more?  I opened a new chat room for us at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4503/room-for-bgm-and-c-marius

Answer (score 4):

You will need licenses for the development environments as well. Microsoft offers MSDN subscription ([Premium](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/premium/overview) includes also SharePoint) for this purpose, and while the subscription is not free, it is *considerably* cheaper than actual production licenses of Windows Server and SharePoint Enterprise.

If you are a startup, see if [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) would suit for you. Also, in case you wonder, TechNet subscription is not suitable for development. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dd362338.aspx) comparison.

After you got the licenses figured out, it is quite alright to have a separate workstation that you use as development "server", and you connect to that using RDP, or just use it directly. There is no requirement to have a rack *server* for development.

Comment: What about using Sharpoint Foundation for development?  Would that platform provide enough for me to make webparts and custom solutions?

Comment: Absolutely (provided that Foundation is sufficient in feature wise), but you will still need Windows Server license and VS license.

Comment: Do the licenses I have for VS 2010 and Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise include the allowance to set up a second copy just for development?

Comment: there is also a 'DreamSpark' program for academic people & institutions (which offers MS software at a discount) - https://www.dreamspark.com/Default.aspx

Comment: VS 2010 and SharePoint 2010 Enterprise do not include development licenses, so you will need separate ones for your development box.

Comment: @jussi-palo - Would you also recommend using a virtual machine?

Comment: If you have powerful workstation at the moment (at least 8GB RAM, Quad Core CPU, at least 7200 rpm HD), you can develop using virtual machine as well. I use 16 GB RAM laptop, SSD and Intel i5 CPU and I'm very happy with the performance (using VMware). If I would choose now, I would take i7 CPU. Not sure how much performance gain it would really bring, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 7 x64 (Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate) then you can run SharePoint on it directly if you like.  This means you make the most use of your available RAM.  However, it does have downsides in that you cant take advantage of things like snapshots that you would get with a virtualization technology like Hyper-V or VMWare.

An easy way to set up your development environment is to use SP Easy Setup scripts which will assist installing all the products you need to get started with SharePoint developent.  They are powershell scripts so you can modify them to your needs if required.  You can find them here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2010/10/28/announcing-sharepoint-easy-setup-for-developers.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That seems like a useful link you provided! +1.  Practically speaking, what is the difference between running all the dev stuff on a virtual machine and running it actually?  Which is the better way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual machine if you can.  With a VM, you can roll back to a pristine state at any time should you mess things up(and you will).  You can also add an AD domain and as many users as you will need to test different security scenarios(security considerations are a big deal in SharePoint development). Also with a VM you can create snapshots for testing your solutions against different patch levels of the product. Lastly, with a VM your regular work station will not get mucked up with all the overhead incurred by a SharePoint installation.

I use Oracle VirtualBox - it's free and performs better than or as well as VMWare or Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question topic has been well addressed by all the answers here. I would like to add a small pointer though - use SSD drives (good reliable ones like Intel or Samsung or any other well-reviewed ones). The SSDs' prices have fallen recently, making it quite affordable. The performance increases in a SharePoint environment using SSDs goes a very long way and tremendously benefiting the developers.

Comment: Do you mean you would recommend a SSD over a HDD?  Yes, I know the question has been well-answered so far, and am almost ready to accept.

Comment: Yes for development (& demos).. there are some mixed results as some feel the gains are only during startup/shutdown time (of the VM /HW) but I think it's a lot more.. here's a small post regarding the SSD improvements -
http://vojtan.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/performance-issd-disk-and-sharepoint-2010/
and another post - http://www.planetwilson.co.uk/2010/03/ssd-goodness-and-sharepoint-virtual-machines/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out CloudShare - they have a load of options and its so quick to get started. Depending on how long you want it for they also do a 30 day fully functioning trial. All of the environments are all pre-configured.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap answer is to install SharePoint onto your Windows 7 Hard Drive. However, your question was "Best" and for that you will need to get VMWorkstation 11.0 + MSDN Premium subscription. You will need to install SP2013, SQL, and AD, and Win all onto their own VM network (so get a host with iCore 7 + 32 GB Ram and a fast Hard Drive. USB 3 is slower but works if you can't get an internal SSD. If you need a step-by-step guide how to do this, just let me know.

If you want the easy way (not the best in my opinion) then login to Azure and create a SP2013 or SP2016 Farm. It has everything I mentioned above but all the configuration is done for you. You login using MSTSC + IP Address to get a VM in the cloud. Once logged in you can install whatever tools you need.

Comment: I ended up installing Windows 7 on VirtualBox.  Worked like a charm too, until management moved to Office365. :(